# AWS_ROLE credentials are not allowed for this account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the below message:

> AWS_ROLE credentials are not allowed for this account.

I am trying to execute the below command to create a stage and the execute a book from my files in S3 to a table into my data warehouse.

```
use schema mydb.[myschema];
create stage mystage
            url='s3://my-bucket'
            credentials = (aws_role = 'arn:aws:iam::[]:role/myrole')
            encryption=(type='AWS_SSE_KMS' kms_key_id = 'aws/key');
```

Comment: Hi,

Did you follow this [setup guide for aws role](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html#option-2-configuring-an-aws-iam-role) ?

Comment: How is AWS_ROLE defined? I think you may be running in an error on permissions for the role that is being used. To list the permissions of the role try SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE aws_test; (great guide for managing the roles and permissions is here https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Capture-Snowflake-Users-Roles-and-Grants-Into-a-Table )

Comment: @holmes840 Yes, I did. It was that documentation that I followed.

Comment: @RachelMcGuigan I guess, in this case, the issue is in the attribute/parameter aws_role, which my snowflake root account is not allowed to use the aws_role as a way to read S3 buckets.

Comment: @RachelMcGuigan I’ve created a ticket and received the answer as my account has been created in Azure, I can’t use the option 2 - Using AWS role to auth into AWS. I used key and secret key for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option 2 is not allowed when the snowflake root account is created in Azure. This answer came to me through the Snowflake support. I then requested them to update the documentation and for me I am using the user and secret key for a while. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the comments I would recommend these changes that by good practice can be done from the suggest:

```
GRANT CREATE STATE ON WAREHOUSE <your_warehouse> TO ROLE aws_test;
```

This is based on the [IAM role setup here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html)
Let me know if that helps?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try it and let you know. I’m following this document and executing the option 2, because I have my role in AWS (SnowflakeRole) and when I’m trying to create the stage in Snowflake I’m using my root user/admin. What is this AWS_test your command is using ? And is there this step on the documentation? Because I haven’t seen it. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I've executed the command: GRANT CREATE STAGE ON WAREHOUSE WHLOADING TO ROLE PROVIDER; and I received the following error: SQL compilation error: Invalid object type 'WAREHOUSE' for privilege 'CREATE STAGE'.

Comment: Apologies I believe I misunderstood. I re-read how the IAM account was set up - and it looks like this account that is managed by the IAM policy that was set up for the IAM role. I see that this now has a role 'provider', is this what the IAM role is called?

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for your answer. My IAM role in AWS called SnowflakeRole and my role in my snowflake database is Provider, but the message that I am receiving is in relation to the parameter AWS_ROLE, which is saying that my account in snowflake is not allowed to use it.

Comment: Jus a additional comment, when I am trying to do it using the option 3 it is working, but it is not the ideal.